# Issue with wordpress site, unable to access management/phpmyadmin/wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

I was just handed a broken Wordpress site that I am now in charge of Administering (administrating?).

All I have is the URL of the site, and some login credentials. When logging into wordpress.com, I am presented with the "wordpress.com/home/mysiteurl.com" page and a basic dashboard. I want to be able to troubleshoot the issues I'm having, as I understand it- I would like to be able to access the wp-admin page, and make changes to wp-admin.php, phpmyadmin, etc.

The main over-arching issue is that when I click almost any of the links in the wp nav bar (including the link to wp administration page), it directs me to a broken log-in page (as if i'm trying to log into the wordpress site itself, not wordpress.com). It's like an endless loop, unable to login to continue- yet I have no access to modify any of the source files in the root wordpress folder. The login page for the wordpress site is broken, but I'm unable to edit that page from my dashboard.

When looking through the info I do have access to- it looks as though the site is hosted by wordpress.com (all the domain registrar information is handled by wordpress.com). I was looking for a cPanel page or something so I could access wp-admin.php to make changes. When looking at the WHOIS information for the domain, the hosting provider is listed as "Automattic" with the nameservers being NS1, NS2, NS3.WORDPRESS.COM. As I understand it, wordpress does not need to be installed to a local server, and is offered as a service from hosting providers. Can wordpress themselves be the host?

So my main question is- Does wordpress need to be installed somewhere (like, on a local computer or a server)? Nobody knows where the root directory for this wordpress site is located, or how to access it. I need to find how to access the admin panel for whoever is hosting this site.

Any way to determine how I might be able to access the back-end of this broken wordpress site?

I've tried: https://example.com:2083/ https://example.com/cpanel https://example.com/wp-admin

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're using WordPress **.com** then you will not be able to access or setup cPanel or PHPMyadmin (or similar services). You can read up on the differences [here](https://wordpress.com/support/com-vs-org/).

If your site is on WordPress.com, it's pretty much off-topic for Stack Overflow as well, as it's more of a customer support question better suited to https://wordpress.com/support/

Answer (score 0):

If you have the site on the "WordPress.com" platform, you can't access to the DB or filesystem of that server.

In this case, "WordPress.com" is the admin of that site; a managed version of "wordpress.org".